# Javascript addRule multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm experimenting with addRule on CSS in HTML. It works fine if I do this:

```
document.styleSheets[0].addRule("#" + id + ':hover', 'max-height: ' + desiredHeight + 'px;');
```

where id and desiredHeight are variables that are already set. This applies a max-height when you hover over the element. My question is this: How can i add a structire like this:

```
body.link, body.appAdd, body.pageLike {
    #id:hover{
        overflow:hidden;
        maxHeight: 400px;
    }
}
```

Please help ;)

Answer (score 0):

That structure has to be compiled down to pure CSS before the browser can understand it.

So in this particular case, it will be something like:

```
document.styleSheets[0].addRule(
    'body.link #'+id+':hover, body.appAdd #'+id+':hover, body.pageLike #'+id+':hover, ',
    'max-height: ' + desiredHeight + 'px;'
);
```

But if you are using the ID in only one place as recommended, all you'll need is (what you already have):

```
document.styleSheets[0].addRule(
    '#'+id+':hover',
    'max-height: ' + desiredHeight + 'px;'
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. The first part will suffice. I need some values to be changed with css by just changing the body ;)